# They are a way to get the current version of the chrome driver by a method?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need a way to get the current web driver version when the test suite  is launch (so not check locally that i know but during the execution)

Comment: What is the programming langauage here

Comment: @Faizan Ahmad:  How do you know if these are the programming language `python python-3.x` ?

Comment: Because selenium is a library of python.

Comment: Its on RobotFrammework Langage

Answer (score 0):

```
print(driver.capabilities['version'])
```

Comment: Please read "[answer]" and "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". It helps more if you supply an explanation why this is the preferred solution and explain how it works. We want to educate, not just provide code.